# Is it possible to always make a trail crossing another trail on top in unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, trail-renderer

I have a couple objects with trail renderers. I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that when an object passes over the trail of another object, it always appears on top ? Because right now the trails are layered by their order in the inspector.

I tried checking if constantly moving the objects on the z axis would fix it, since when crossing another trail, the object would always have a larger z value than the trail at that point, but it didn't work.

I'm using the trail renderer in unity 2D

[image: Here purple is always on top and orange is last]

Comment: You may be interested in [unity 2D sorting manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html). Will this solve your problem?